# Getting Error in Implementing IDisposable in C# code

Tags: c#, idisposable

I am trying to Dispose object once I finished and I am getting following error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'App.Entities.Security.EBSCredentialEntity' to type 'System.IDisposable
```

### Object Code

```
 private EBSCredentialEntity _ServiceCredentialObject;

 private void InitializeEBSCredentials()
    {
           _ServiceCredentialObject = new EBSCredentialEntity() {

            UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EBS_UserName"],
            //remaining code
        };

    }
```

### Error Code

```
  private void DisposeEBSCredentialObject()
    {
        if (_ServiceCredentialObject != null)
        {
            ((IDisposable)_ServiceCredentialObject).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I am calling DisposeEBSCredentialObject() from another method

Comment: does `EBSCredentialEntity` implement `IDisposable`? If so, why do you cast it?

Comment: Can you share ```EBSCredentialEntity``` and how you are using it?

Answer (score 2):

To dispose of an object its type must be Disposable.  So is your class EBSCredentialEntity disposable, i.e. does it implement IDisposable?

If it does then you don't need to do cast it as you show in your posted code.

Comment: It is not answer for question, so it is should be a comment, I think.

Comment: It is an answer to the question because OP now knows that his class must implement `IDisposable.` Butf it doesn't implement it it might be an indicator that it doesn't use any unmanaged resources that need to be disposed.

Comment: It is not even a question.

Comment: The question is: "Why do i get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'App.Entities.Security.EBSCredentialEntity' to type 'System.IDisposable and how can i fix it?"

Comment: My original point was actually phrased as a question, although providing all of the required information.  I've edited it now to be a statement, but the original comment made by tym32167 was correct

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeach, answer was edited after I wrote my comment, so now it looks like answer :D Thx, LordWilmore

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement interface [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public EBSCredentialEntity : IDisposable
```

Also, if you use C# 6, you can write like this:

```
private void DisposeEBSCredentialObject()
{
    (_ServiceCredentialObject as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
}
```

But we know, that _ServiceCredentialObject is IDisposable by design, so, we can skip casting:

```
private void DisposeEBSCredentialObject()
{
    _ServiceCredentialObject?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: IMHO I think your second suggestion is a bad idea. We have type safety exactly for this kind of moments : removing it using a as and null check is a yellow flag for me!

Comment: I am implemented as you suggested, no error but I still can see values in object from I call dispose method,

Comment: @toxic `Dispose` does not mean `delete object from memory`. You should read about garbage collector (GC) in C#, and memory management. Dispose method is for *unmanaged* resources. All other objects will be collected by GC. Aslo, check how is your method Dispose implemented. Do you clean all data you don't need any more?

Comment: @Backs Dispose for disposing, it can be for managed and unmanaged resources. It depends of where it was called. If Dispose was called by user code, it should free all resources. If Dispose was called from finalizer (which called by GC), it should to release only unmanaged resources. (sample https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Common/Core/DisposeObject.cs )

Comment: yes I need to complete destroy object at the end of its use

Answer (score 1):

Your class should implement `IDisposable` interface:

```
public class EBSCredentialEntity : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // cleanup code here
    }
}
```

Then you can also use handy `using` statement to avoid calling `Dispose` method directly:

```
using (EBSCredentialEntity entity = new EBSCredentialEntity())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I need to call dispose method directly

Comment: Of course you can do that. The `Dispose` method is public.